# AD username on windows 10 in a windows 8.1 store app

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal

I'm developing a 8.1 app that needs to be compatible with windows 10.

I'm trying to get the Username of the user logged in, but it always returns a emtry string.

How do i get the username of a user in a windows 8.1 store app running on a windows 10 pc?

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetPrincipalNameAsync()
```

and

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.GetDomainNameAsync()
```

always return an empty string

Is there another way of getting the AD user name of a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the description in the **Remarks** section of [UserInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.aspx) class document:

> **Important**  The **UserInformation** class is not supported on Windows 10 or later. Use the [**User**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.user.aspx) class instead.
>
> **Windows 10:**
>
> Apps compiled for Windows 8 that use the **UserInformation** class no longer return user information when running on Windows 10. This is because in Windows 10, apps do not have access to user information without explicit user consent, unlike in Windows 8 where this permission is granted by default.
>
> If you have a Windows 8 app that uses the **UserInformation** class, you should migrate your app to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and access the [**User**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.user.aspx) class instead. Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps that access user information are now expected to declare a new capability, uap:userAccountInformation, and call new APIs, **[Windows.System.User.FindAllAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.user.findallasync.aspx)** and **[User.GetPropertiesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn996552.aspx)**, to get the data.

And if you use [UserInformation.NameAccessAllowed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.nameaccessallowed.aspx) property in your code, you will find its value is `false`.

> If this property is **false**, the **[GetDisplayNameAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getdisplaynameasync.aspx)**, **[GetDomainNameAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getdomainnameasync.aspx)**, **[GetFirstNameAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getfirstnameasync.aspx)**, and **[GetLastNameAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getlastnameasync.aspx)** methods return an empty string, while the **[GetAccountPicture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getaccountpicture.aspx)** and **[GetSessionInitiationProtocolUriAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getsessioninitiationprotocoluriasync.aspx)** methods return a null value.

So I think to get the user name on Windows 10, you have to migrate your app to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and access the [User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.user.aspx) class instead. For details, you can check the [User information sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserInfo) at GitHub.

Comment: And there are no other way of getting the username?

Comment: @MikkelGunvald: AFAIK, there is no other way. Since Windows 10 has changed the mechanism for getting username, we have to declare a new capability and call new APIs.